# Outline when clicking an input [type="submit"] in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm designing a form for (X)HTML. Since I don't like the standard styling for the

```
<input type = "submit">
```

I've changed the style of this input using CSS. The problem now is that when I click on the button, a yellow border around the element will appear in Chrome, but not in IE nor in Firefox. But if I remove the CSS styling (going to default behaviour), there is no problem in Chrome. I don't understand why my CSS code makes Chrome behave in this manner.

The code is (it is based on code generated from [this site](http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
        .TestButton{background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
            background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
            background-color:#ededed;border-radius:6px; text-indent:0;border:1px solid #dcdcdc; color:#007fd0;font-family:arial;
            font-size:15px; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal;  height:35px;    line-height:35px;   width:135px;text-align:center;
            float:right; margin-right:20px;} 
        .TestButton:hover {
            background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
            background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% ); 
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
            background-color:#dfdfdf;}
        .TestButton:active {position:relative;top:1px;}
    </style>
    <title>HTML</title>
</head>

<body>      
    <form action="Action.php" method="post">
        <p><input type="text" name="UserName"></p>
        <p><input class="TestButton" type="submit" value="Test"/></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

From my web search it seems that this problem is related to the "outline" property. And indeed if I add the following CSS code:

```
.TestButton:focus {outline:none;}
```

this yellow border disappears. But then I get an [accessibility problem for keyboard users](http://outlinenone.com/).

Comment: There is no solution then.. either it's there or it isn't.

Comment: You could always change the outline property to better suit your design instead of just removing it entirely.

Comment: Can you add a border/border color manipulation instead?

Comment: Changing the outline property could be a (not ideal) solution. What baffles me is why this problem disappears when I comment the CSS code...

Comment: crbug.com/305356 This is an intentional behavior.

Comment: @int32_t: Thanks for the link. At least I know that I'm not the only one with this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome's default stylesheet applies a yellow outline to form elements which have focus.

If you don't want this yellow outline, yet still want to maintain accessibility for keyboard users, you can find other ways to make it visible that the button has focus. For example, you can use a different background colour for the button:

```
.TestButton:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: /* some darker colour than the original colour */;
}
```

Comment: But if Google Chrome's default stylesheet applies a yellow outline to form elements, in this case the yellow outline should also appear even if I didn't add no CSS style, right? But the strange thing is that if I comment the CSS, the outline disappears...

Comment: @user2958403 that is pretty strange, never noticed it before. It may have something to do with the fact that the operating system also affects the default styling of form elements (I am using Windows)

Comment: This definitively seems to have to do with the version of the operating system/Chrome. The problem appeared in a computer running Windows 8 and a version of Chrome which I'll update later. Now I tried the same code on a computer running Windows 7 with Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m, and I had no problems. Anyway, I don't understand how the user could benefit from a yellow border around a button which the user has just clicked (the yellow border doesn't seem to provide any gain from an accessibility point of view).

Comment: The version of Chrome which I was using when I got problematic behavior was 30.0.1599.101 m

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome's default stylesheet applies a yellow outline to form elements which have focus.

```
-webkit-appearance: caret;
```